# Resetting elements CSS for usage with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm about to use Bootstrap in an already existing site, but I don't want/need to implement it over the whole site. In fact, I just wanted to use it in specific places. I looked at [Bootstrap's site](http://getbootstrap.com/), but couldn't find a direct answer to my questions:

1. Is it possible to insert an HTML element where Bootstrap is
   applicable and just on that one?
2. On that HTML can I, somehow, reset all CSS customizations previously stated and also the styles that may have cascaded from other elements?

Comment: Just use Bootstrap specific classes for that one element you want to apply it to and use your own classes for all other elements. However, if you're just using Bootstrap on one element, it would probably be better to just recreate the Bootstrap styling yourself for that one element. The framework is intended to be used site-wide, not on specific elements.

Comment: I understand my scenario is less than ideal, but right now I think that using Bootstrap is easier than recreating some stuff.
When you say "Just use Bootstrap specific classes for that one element you want to apply ", won't Bootstrapped-elements inherit things? Example, if I have a "global" p{font-size=16px} is there a way simple way to prevent all those styles from applying to the Bootstrapped-elements, even if it requires jQuery?

Comment: Yes, by loading a reset after loading Bootstrap, but that would be pointless. Your best bet is to just recreate the styling you're going for on that specific element and not use Bootstrap at all. Sometimes the easier solution is not the best.